# How to find the clusters that produce the maximum colMeans in R?

Tags: r, k-means

I have a data frame like

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  1  2
2  0  1  0
3  3  0  3
....
```

and I have a vector of the same length as the number of rows in the data frame (it's the `cluster` from kmeans, if that matters)

```
[1] 2 2 1...
```

From those I can get the `colMeans` for each cluster, like

```
cm1 <- colMeans(df[fit$cluster==1,])
cm2 <- colMeans(df[fit$cluster==2,])
```

(I don't think I should do that part explicitly, but that's how I'm thinking about the problem.)

What I want is to get, for each column of the data frame, the value from the vector for which the colMeans is the maximum. Also I'd like to do (separately is fine) the second-highest, third, etc. So in the example I would want the output to be a vector with one element for each column of the data frame:

```
1 2 1...
```

because for the first column of the data frame, the column mean for the first cluster is 3, while the column mean for the second cluster is 0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `cluster` vector is of the same length as the number of rows of 'df', `split` the data by the 'cluster' column into a `list`,

```
lst1 <- lapply(split(df, fit$cluster), function(x) stack(colMeans(x)))
dat <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, cluster = names(lst1), lst1)) 
aggregate(values ~ ind, dat, FUN = which.max)
```

---

If we need to subset multiple element based on column means, create the 'cluster' column in the data, reshape to 'long' format (or use `summarise/across`), grouped by 'cluster', 'name', get the `mean` of 'value', `arrange` the column 'name' and the 'value' in `desc`ending order, then return the `n` rows with `slice_head`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(cluster = fit$cluster) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -cluster) %>%
   group_by(cluster, name) %>%
   summarise(value = mean(value), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
   arrange(name, desc(value)) %>% 
   group_by(name) %>%
   slice_head(n = 2)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 0L, 3L), V2 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), V3 = c(2L, 
0L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))

fit <- structure(list(cluster = c(2, 2, 1)), class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```